# Increasing number of Dots

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the 10-letter answer I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

```
                              (5)
                              (4)
                              (6)
                              (4)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for

> **DIMENSIONS**?

Because your image depicts

> from top to bottom:
>  A **point**. (5)
>  The endpoints of a **line**. (4)
>  The corners of a **square**. (6)
>  The vertices of a **cube**. (4)
>  And each of these objects contains more dimensions (and dots, hence the title) than the last.
>  [image]

Comment: Yep, that's the answer I was looking for, well done!

Comment: where the rot13(qvzrafvbaf vapernfr sebz mreb gb guerr)

Comment: I can't wait what a 4-dimensional shape would look like under dots. >:)